# Monotouch.Dialog stretching UIView in Section

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I have an image, a logo, that appears at the top of my Monotouch.Dialog using this code:

```
        var logo = new UIImageView(logonLogoPNG)
            {
                AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin |
                                   UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | 
                                   UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin |
                                   UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin,
            };
        var secLogo = new Section(logo);
```

The problem is that when the form shows in an iPad the logo stretches. The Autosizingmask doesn't appear to be helping.

How do I stop the stretch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
        //Add a centered Logo in the top Section of the Monotouch.dialog
        var logo = new UIImageView(image) 
                       {  AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleMargins};
        var logoView = new UIView(new RectangleF(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width,logo.Frame.Height));
        logo.Center = logoView.Center;
        logoView.AddSubview(logo);
```

The trick was to set the Center of the Logo to the Center of the containing View then make the logo flow with flexible margins.